# Need to counteract player movement somehow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code, and, before anybody says it, I do not want to use translate or a character controller or any of that. Basically, with my current code, as soon as I stop holding any of the input keys, my character slides all over the place. How can I counteract this? By the way, a lot of these values defined at the beginning I have changed in the editor.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce = 1;
    [SerializeField] float distanceFromGround = .5f;
    [SerializeField] float maxSpeed = 1;

    float currSpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * currSpeed;
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * currSpeed;

        if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Jump") == 1 && Grounded())
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
        }

        Vector3 movePos = transform.right * x + transform.forward * y;
        Vector3 newMovePos = new Vector3(movePos.x, 0, movePos.z);

        rb.AddForce(newMovePos);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        currSpeed = speed;
        if (!Grounded())
        {
            currSpeed = speed / 2;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0 && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0)
        {
            currSpeed = speed * .75f;
        }
        if(rb.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxSpeed);
        }
    }

    bool Grounded()
    {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distanceFromGround);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `addForce` in the opposite direction of travel

Comment: You could set the [drag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-drag.html) on your [rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) to some value.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding, the drag helps but it does not fix the problem. Luc, if it's not too much trouble, could you create an example of this? I've tried to with mixed results but never got it to work, which is why I posted this question in the first place. I want to know how to specifically.

Comment: @toesnub question unclear, do you want the character to cease lateral movement immediately when no input is given?

Comment: I just need some way to counteract the slipperiness. Not necessarily stop as a whole but just make the movement less sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop all movements by making rigidbody kinematic if condition is met by simply adding rb.isKinematic =true/false;

Or directly affect rb velocity in update.
Sor example you'd have in your update

rb.velocity=slowedVelocity;
so whenever you'd not be adding any velocity you are reducing it.

Another thing you migth be asking is to jsut add constraints in your editor so player is not moving and rotating in ways you do not waint it to do.